# RecordTriggerAutolaunched flow Not firing

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, approval-process, approval-step

I have done field update in approval process final approval action. I have created a RecordTriggered flow
based on this objects field update. In the flow am updating its parent record field. But the field update is not happening.

Is the orderofExecution is causing an issue?? The same thing i can achieve from process builder but its not happening via record triggered flow. If i do normal field update via details page recordtriggered flow is working but not from approval process.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same issue. You are not alone!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was not able to get it to work as intended. There is effectively no debug information since the flows are not invoked by the approval process. I was able to get my flow to fire by performing the DML directly on the record.

My eventual workaround:

1. Change the type of flow so that it can be invoked by a process
2. Create process with appropriate entry criteria and pass the record from the process to the flow

Answer (score 0):

Approval Process will not trigger record triggered flow. Auto launched Flow has to be called via process builder to achieve the requirement. From the Process Builder, you can pass the record details of the record that triggered the process into the flow.
[image]

[image]