# Flow Builder not firing up after approval process

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, process-builder, visual-workflow

I have a custom object "Custom1" on which we added an Approval process. The process is easy when the object is approved by the approver then I have a Final Approval Actions that is set to update a field in "Custom1" Called is_approved ( True/False - Checkbox)

Then using a Flow builder I set that if the field is is_approved: True then it should trigger the flow that will update a field in many records linked to "Custom1"

For some reason, the Flow Builder is not triggered when it happens after the approval process. However, if I edit the field is_approved to TRUE manually then the flow is triggered

Could you please help me to trigger it after the approval process?

FYI:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been incorporated into the API version v54.0. To get the flow to be fired from an approval process update the flow itself needs to be saved in that version or higher.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment on Alex's answer. Sandbox was just updated to Spring 22 and flow was not triggered. Is there a setup missing?

Comment: Robert, I left out an important fact: If you have an existing Record-triggered flow that was created before Spring '22, you need to resave it using the Spring '22 'API Version' of 54 (or higher) in order to have it trigger this way. (See https://drive.google.com/file/d/178CjjDB5obFdVQnKBTwZQSO64gnFZcz2/view?usp=sharing) Salesforce did this so that existing flows wouldn't suddenly start triggering unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your approval process field update has "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change" checked.

If it is checked, this feature may not be supported.  You can work around it by having process builder invoke the Flow instead, as noted in this similar question:
[RecordTriggerAutolaunched flow Not firing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318914/recordtriggerautolaunched-flow-not-firing)