# After approval process I need to get the user who requests for the approval

Tags: process-builder, approval-process, field-update, automation

[image]

[image]

Here in the first image I have  given a field update so that my 'Requested by' field has to be updated to the person who requests for the approval.But here instead of getting the user who requests I have only an option to give one user's name manually.

I have to update it to the person who requests for the approval be it anyone.

Should I use any automation tools for this-process builder or screen flow for this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of capturing Initial Submitter in a Lookup field?

If its just for reporting purpose, you can use reports and fetch those details there

Or if you want to capture just the name you can go with a Text field and while updating the field you can opt for a formula editor and update with User> User.Name instead.

Or, if you want the User look-up instead of a text field I guess that cannot be done using a field update on Submission actions. Instead go with a Flow/Process Builder on Submission(you have to update another field so you can trigger your Flow and make sure "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change" is checked). You can check this link for flow/process builder [RecordTriggerAutolaunched flow Not firing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318914/recordtriggerautolaunched-flow-not-firing)